# how stop recyclerview to listen on click when click on internal button

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

My recylerView has custom layout which consists of button.when I clicking on button, onClick fire on both button and recylerView.Is there any way to stop recyler fire on click when clicking on button.I am not posting code because it is very large.

Custom Layout

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:id="@+id/custom_results_adapter_layout2"
        android:visibility="visible"

        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="New"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="#00f"
                    android:id="@+id/custom_result_new_old2"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2d"
                    android:id="@+id/custom_result_time2"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/custom_results_result2"
                android:textColor="#000"

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Mid Term Result"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>



            <Button
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/results_publish"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"

      android:background="@drawable/button_signup_people_boundary"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="Publish"
                android:onClick="publickClick"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />





        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Main Layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="activities.Result.Results">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="?
        attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:onClick="onBack"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_arrow" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Results"
                    android:textColor="#212d19"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/results_recyler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myFabResultsUpload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="onResultsFab"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:rippleColor="#44ffffff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_white" />
          <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/myFabResultsAddEditor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:onClick="onAddEditorFab"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:rippleColor="#44ffffff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_addeditoricon" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/results_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_result_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:text="No Result Found"
        android:textColor="#99000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/retry"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_boundary"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Retry"
        android:alpha="0.25"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter

```
           package Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.BitmapImageViewTarget;
import com.espero.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import Model.ResultsModel;

import static Classes.RoundedCorner.getRoundedCornerBitmap;

/**
 * Created by parvesh_dhull on 27/1/17.
 */

public class Results_recyler_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Results_recyler_adapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private List<ResultsModel> resultsModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "EVENT";
    private List<String> readedResults = new ArrayList<>();
    private Long schoolTime;
    private Boolean adminFlag = false;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private String schoolID = "";

    public Results_recyler_adapter(List<ResultsModel> resultsModels, List<String> readedResults, Context context, Long schoolTime, Boolean adminFlag, FirebaseDatabase database, String schoolID) {
        this.resultsModels = resultsModels;
        this.readedResults = readedResults;
        this.context = context;
        this.schoolTime = schoolTime;
        this.adminFlag = adminFlag;
        this.database = database;
        this.schoolID = schoolID;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_result_adapter, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public void refresh(List<ResultsModel> resultsModels, List<String> readedResults, Boolean adminFlag) {
        this.resultsModels = resultsModels;
        this.readedResults = readedResults;
        this.adminFlag = adminFlag;
//
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("Result",Integer.toString(resultsModels.size()));
        return resultsModels.size();

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView result1, result2, date1, date2, newOld1, newOld2;
        private LinearLayout layout1, layout2;
        private Button publish;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            newOld1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_result_new_old);
            newOld2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_result_new_old2);
            result1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_results_result);
            result2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_results_result2);
            date2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_result_time2);
            date1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_result_time);
            layout1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_results_adapter_layout1);
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_results_adapter_layout2);
            publish = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.results_publish);


            publish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("Result","clickInAdapter");
                }
            });




        }
    }


}
```

RecylerTouchListner Class

```
    package Classes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by parvesh_dhull on 15/2/17.
 */

public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
    }
```

Main Activity code for on click

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {


            Log.d("Result","recylerClicked");
      }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            if(schoolID.equals(UID)){
            deleteResult(resultsModels.size(),position);    }
        }

    }));
```

Comment: Post the relevant code please bud, it's an incentive for readers to answer your questions more specifically to the problem you have, at the moment it's a rather broad question.

Comment: done adding, tell me if you need anything more

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the onClick method in XML to trigger a click event in a RecyclerView, try triggering a click event in your RecyclerView.Adapter or RecyclerView.ViewHolder. This should solve your problem. (you can still call the same method PublickClick inside the onClickListener within those classes, but then it wouldn't trigger twice)

Comment: I added clickListner in RecylerView.ViewHolder but I still get same problem. I logged and found onClick on recylerView is firing first then onButton

Comment: Post the onBindViewHolder method in your adapter, and the onclick logic for your viewholder.

Comment: I added my adapter code,please check out.

Comment: No its recyler view touch lisener is trigrring when clicking on publish button,..I also added my code of recyler touch listner

Comment: Okay, i'll post an answer in a second.

Comment: okey, thanks in advance for help